# How to express lifetime for Rust iterator for a container

Tags: rust

I have a circular buffer like this:

```
struct CircularBuffer<T: Copy> {
    seqno: usize,
    data: Vec<T>,
}
```

And I want to create an external struct being an iterator. This struct would refer to the internal data vector of the `CircularBuffer` like this one:

```
struct CircularBufferIterator<'a, T: 'a + Copy> {
    buffer: &'a CircularBuffer<T>,
    position: usize,
    limit: usize,
}
```

This is the best I could come up with that actually compiles. Can you please suggest a better way to express that the `CircularBufferIterator` depends on the `CircularBuffer` object?

What troubles me is `T: 'a + Copy`. I wonder if it is possible or it makes sense to say that not the `T` type, but `CircularBuffer<T>` is the one `CircularBufferIterator` depends on.

The part I don't see is why do I need to add the `'a` lifetime to `T`. Cannot that be `T: Copy`, without a lifetime? In other words, I cannot see a case when `T` reference outlives the `CircularBuffer`. It is the `CircularBuffer` reference that outlives the `CircularBufferIterator`.

The `CircularBuffer` and the context comes from [this blog post](http://dbeck.github.io/Learning-Rust-Iterator/).

Comment: It's unclear to me what the problem is with the solution presented. `T` has to outlive `'a` to prevent dangling pointers; `T` has to be `Copy` because you defined `CircularBuffer` as such.

Comment: Thank you for the formatting help. I am not sure if there is a problem. I just don't fully understand how it works. The part I don't see is why do I need to add 'a lifetime to T. Cannot that be T: Copy, without a lifetime? In other words I cannot see a case when T reference outlives the CircularBuffer. It is the CircularBuffer reference that outlives the CBIterator. So I was looking for a nicer way to express exactly that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why do I need to add the `'a` lifetime to `T`

You aren't adding a lifetime to `T`; you are saying that whatever `T` is chosen, it can only **contain** references that outlive `'a`. If that wasn't the case, then we might have a reference to a type that has a reference that is now invalid. Using that invalid reference would lead to memory unsafety; a key thing that Rust seeks to avoid.

---

*I originally thought you were asking how to remove the `Copy` bound, so here's all that I typed up.*

One change would be to remove the `Copy` bound from `CircularBuffer` but leaving it on the implementation of the methods. Then you don't need it on the iterator at all:

```
struct CircularBuffer<T> {
    seqno: usize,
    data: Vec<T>,
}

struct CircularBufferIterator<'a, T: 'a> {
    buffer: &'a CircularBuffer<T>,
    position: usize,
    limit: usize,
}
```

Another change would be to completely eschew the direct reference to the `CircularBuffer` altogether, and keep direct iterators into the `Vec`:

```
struct CircularBufferIterator<'a, T: 'a> {
    first: std::slice::Iter<'a, T>,
    second: Option<std::slice::Iter<'a, T>>,
}
```

However, looking at the `Iterator` implementation, I see it returns a `T`, not a `&T`, so you ultimately need a type that is `Copy` or `Clone`. You'll note that the standard library doesn't require this because it returns a reference to the item in the collection. If you do need a non-reference, that's what `into_iter` or [`Iterator::cloned`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned) is for.

Comment: This clarifies a lot, thank you very much! I really like the slice idea. I will experiment with it. I believe that is the closest to what I wanted to achieve.